# What does the vertical bar on the left mean on words with friends 2?

Tags: words-with-friends, words-with-friends-2

[image: vertical bar on game screen of words with Friends 2]

Anyone know what the colours on the vertical bar on the left mean in the new Words with Friends 2 game?

Comment: Never played, but it could it mean *your turn* vs *their turn*?  Also, great image for clarification!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there are different sections for whose turn it is to play.  It's not that.